# mapping between xlxwriter and xlwt

Tags: python, xlwt

How to map `xlsxwriter` col width 10.9 size to `xlwt` col width size?

I don't have an idea about `xlsxwriter` how it measurs size. If I give same it throws an error saying it accept only integers.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your current code to your question. This will help people to understand your problem better (in turn helping you to get better answers).

Comment: xlsxwriter: sheet1.set_column(2,2,10.86,format_nbr2) xlwt code: sheet1.col(2).width = 10.86